# Как обрабатывать изменение ориентации экрана в фрагменте программно?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть 3 фрагмента, они лежат в `viewPager`, только для одного из них мне нужно менять layout при смене ориентации устройства. У `Activity` стоит флаг `configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`, ее перерисовывать не нужно, только один фрагмент. У меня создана папка layout-land, ориентация меняется, только если прокручивать `viewPager`, то есть, когда пересоздается фрагмент.

Я понимаю что есть onConfigChanges и там нужно как-то обрабатывать то ли замену лайаута то ли операции какие-то с адаптером, гугл выдает в основном примеры с активити без таких флагом, и без адаптеров.

Что у меня есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрещать активити пересоздание - плохая практика, даже если вы думаете, что перересоваывать ее не нужно.

Comment: @pavlofff
Где-то я такое читал, но весомых аргументов я пока не слышал.

Comment: @pavlofff
[Документация](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) google говорит, что это вовсе не плохая практика, если так действительно нужно.

Comment: Во первых внимательно почитайте, что пишут в документации, а во вторых - вам то как раз нужно обратное. Не хотите делать, как положено - придумывайте какие то костыли теперь для проблемы, которая решается естественным образом при правильной разработке.

Comment: @pavlofff, я не согласен с тем, что это плохая практика. Тем более, что к вопросу это не относится.

Comment: Попробуйте в onConfigurationChange заново добавить фрагмент, который нужно перерисовать. А если он во ViewPager, то вызовите у Адаптера notifyDataSetInvalidated, или как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда в таких ситуациях кажется, что решение должно быть замудренное и сложно в реализации. На самом деле оно было в 3 строчки:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
    viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    View view = onCreateView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), viewGroup, null); viewGroup.addView(view);

}
```

Перерисовка фрагмента не самая лучшая идея, если он хранит в себе какие-нибудь данные(воспроизводит видео, работа с картами и тд), т.к. у меня никаких динамически изменяемых данных нет, и мне нужно было отобразить то же самое, только в другой ориентации, я использовал это подход, если вам нужно сменить ориентацию и не потерять данные вам [сюда](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) и стоит почитать [это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146632/)

На счет дискуссии в комментариях, документация по отношению к активити [советует   не использовать](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) в манифесте `configChanges`. Но как показывает практика, в некоторых случая без него не обойтись, в моем случае это было работа с таймерами, где каждый в отдельном потоке, и при повороте перерисовывать не нужно, а лишь отображать новый layout с старыми данными.

Надеюсь кому-то это поможет.